# Building other, dependent projects with Ant

Tags: java, ant, build, target

Let me preface by saying that I am new to Ant.  As in, I just started learning it 2 days ago in order to accomplish this task.

What I'm trying to do is create a "master" ant script that calls several other ant scripts.  For example:

```
Project A
 - contains build.xml, target "makeProjectAjar"
 - output: A.jar

Project B
 - contains build.xml, target "makeProjectBjar"
 - output: B.jar

Project C
 - contains build.xml, target "makeProjectCjar"
 - output: C.jar

Project D
 - contains build.xml, target "finalPackage"
 - Must first build Project A, Project B, Project C
 - Copy A.jar, B.jar, C.jar to Project D
 - Package all of this into D.jar
```

Right now I have all of the individual builds for A, B, and C working.  By this, I mean I can run 'ant' from any of these folders and it will build the project and produce a jar file.  If I build A, B, and C this way, I have 3 jar files.  I can then copy them into D and package it into the final jar.  That works fine.

But what I'd like is to be able to trigger the A, B, and C builds from within build.xml of Project D.  I've tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="CommonJava" default="makeCommonJavaJar" basedir=".">

    <import file="../Common/build.xml"/>
    <import file="../CommonAndroid/build.xml"/>

    <target name="makeCommonJavaJar" description="Create a jar for the CommonJava project"
        depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="build" />
        <jar jarfile="./build/commonjava.jar" includes="*.class" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build" />
    </target>

    <target name="build+package" description="Build all prerequisites and package them">
        <antcall target="makeCommonJar"/>
        <antcall target="makeAndroidJar"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

makeCommonJar is a target in Common/build.xml (Project A) and makeAndroidJar is a target in ../CommonAndroid/build.xml (Project B).  However, it seems that when using `<import>`, it runs from the context of the calling folder.  Meaning resources referenced by Project B are unavailable since it's running from Project D.  Does that make sense?

Long question short... using Ant, how can I call build.xml files in other projects in order to build those projects first?

Comment: If you turn inheritRefs to true, does that fix the issue? http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html

Comment: offtopic: if you started to learn packaging / building frameworks in java, consider learning maven instead of ant. It's worth trying

Comment: The basedir of imported build file will be overwritten by the importing file's. Try using `<ant>` as it is designed to run external build file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some general guidelines (not rules, Ant is quite liberal):

- a build.xml is generally designed to be run on a specific project, so it is not 'imported' in other builds
- the `import` task is generally used to share some comme piece of build mechanic, not a piece of build workflow like you are doing. For instance a target to build jar, parameterized by some properties like the target directory.
- the `subant` and `ant` tasks are preferred used to trigger builds of other project

So here is what would look like a build.xml for project D:

```
<project name="CommonJava" default="makeCommonJavaJar" basedir=".">

    <target name="build-deps">
        <ant antfile="../Common/build.xml" target="makeCommonJar"/>
        <ant antfile="../CommonAndroid/build.xml" target="makeAndroidJar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="makeCommonJavaJar" depends="build-deps">
        <mkdir dir="build" />
        <jar jarfile="./build/commonjava.jar" includes="*.class" />
    </target>

</project>
```

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html

Comment: Perfect... I came to the same conclusion yesterday as well.  This is exactly what I was looking for.