# Using Ant to build dependencies of the current build target

Tags: java, ant

Say I have a library and a binary target, let's call them `MyLib` and `MyBin`,
`MyBin` depends on `MyLib`.

I'm trying to create an Ant buildfile for `MyBin` that first builds `MyLib` and then includes it in the classpath when building `MyBin`.

I've tried using Ant tasks as in [Building other, dependent projects with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030751/building-other-dependent-projects-with-ant) .

However, it's not working, and from `ant -v` I think the `MyBin` `build-deps` target is not even building `MyLib`.  Seems like it's confusing `MyBin` and `MyLib` properties? I'm not sure how to prevent this though.

I'm dumping only `MyBin/build.xml` below, but the `MyLib` is almost identical, except it does not have the `build-deps` target.

```
<project name="MyBin" default="main" basedir=".">
    <property name="projectName" value="MyBin" />
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="bin" />
    <property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
    <property name="dist.lib.dir" location="dist/lib" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />


<target name="build-deps" depends="init">
<!-- MyLib main target does clean -> build -> jar to dist folder -->
<!-- Its build.xml uses many of the same property values as above -->
        <ant antfile="../MyLib/build.xml" target="main"/>
</target>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/">
        <include name="../MyLib/dist/**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<!-- Need classpath to run this -->
<target name="compile" depends="build-deps" description="compile the source ">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}"
                   destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="classpath" />
</target>

<!-- Group all dependencies into a big dependency-all.jar -->
<target name="copy-dependencies">

    <mkdir dir="${dist.lib.dir}" />

    <jar jarfile="${dist.lib.dir}/dependencies-all.jar">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </zipgroupfileset>
    </jar>

</target>

<!-- jar it, extract above dependency-all.jar and zip it with project files -->
<target name="jar" depends="compile, copy-dependencies"
            description="package, output to JAR">

    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.lib.dir}" />

    <jar jarfile="${dist.dir}/${projectName}.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}" />
        </manifest>
        <zipfileset src="${dist.lib.dir}/dependencies-all.jar"
                            excludes="META-INF/*.SF" />
    </jar>

</target>

<target name="clean" description="clean up">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
</target>

<!-- Default, run this -->
<target name="main" depends="clean, compile, jar" />
</project>
```

What I see with `ant -v in MyBin` is something along the lines of:

```
build-deps:
Project base dir set to: /MyBin
      [ant] calling target(s) [main] in build file /MyLib/build.xml
parsing buildfile /MyLib/build.xml with URI = file:/MyLib/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /MyBin
Override ignored for property "projectName"
Override ignored for property "build.dir"
Override ignored for property "dist.dir"
Override ignored for property "dist.lib.dir"
Override ignored for property "lib.dir"
[pathconvert] Set property classpath.name = 
      [ant] Entering /MyLib/build.xml...
Build sequence for target(s) `main' is [clean, init, copy-dependencies, jar, main]
Complete build sequence is [clean, init, copy-dependencies, jar, main, ]

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /MyBin/bin
   [delete] Deleting directory /MyBin/bin

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /MyBin/bin

copy-dependencies:
      [ant] Exiting /MyLib/build.xml.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your specific question:

> seems like it's confusing MyBin and MyLib properties? I'm not sure how
>   to prevent this though.

You are using this to invoke the `MyLib` build:

```
<ant antfile="../MyLib/build.xml" target="main" />
```

A build invoked via the `<ant>` task this way by default inherits all properties from the caller, including `basedir`, hence the build is run in the wrong place.

Instead you could use, for example:

```
<ant dir="../MyLib" />
```

That will run `build.xml` in the specified directory, set the `basedir` property, and call the default target, which should be `main` if you are using a very similar buildfile for the library as you say. If you don't want to inherit properties from `MyBin` when executing the `MyLib` task, specify `inheritAll=false` in the task.

From the [`<ant>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) task docs for the `dir` attribute:

> the directory to use as a basedir for the new Ant project (unless
>   useNativeBasedir is set to true). Defaults to the current project's
>   basedir, unless inheritall has been set to false, in which case it
>   doesn't have a default value. This will override the basedir setting
>   of the called project. Also serves as the directory to resolve the
>   antfile and output attribute's values (if any).

Comment: I'm getting a different error message now, and it's pretty clear that it's configured to follow `MyBin/build.xml` ant tasks from `../MyLib`, as the error message is from not being able to find a directory that *only* is mentioned from `MyBin/build.xml` (I've tried specifying `antfile` explicitly as well as just `dir`).

I want a hermetic `MyLib` ant build followed by a `MyBin` (which then pulls `MyLib` ouptut into classpath). I think you've pointed me in right direction though, will spend some time with the various ant tasks options and report back.

Comment: Yup, `inheritAll=false1 seemed to do the trick to force `MyLib` build to be hermetic.