# How to create single build file to create jar file of project having other project dependency in ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am new to ant and I have tried and googled lots of sites to get an idea to build my project but I am not getting the proper way and confused too.

I have a project A having projecting dependencies on project B and further project B has the dependency on project C and third party jar abc.jar and that dependencies I have defined through eclipse build path. I want to create single ant build file that will compile all the projects and give me a single file. I have read many posts related to this but I am not getting the proper way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building other, dependent projects with Ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030751/building-other-dependent-projects-with-ant)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem it sounds like you are creating a framework for a plugin.

Or in another way, you are following what seems to be along the lines of creating an eclipse rcp application.

It sounds like you are getting there.  One of the steps in the rcp application process is creating a feature project.  The feature project delegates building your dependent projects to itself via ant.  Ant is defined via a target.  The target is a list of all the dependencies needed for the build of all your projects.  The target needs to reside in your parent project where your code lives or /src folder lives.

Check out vogel's eclipse rcp tutorial and see if an rcp app is for your needs.

I'm just learning all this stuff as well, this is best practice for creating deployable apps as well as creating a plugin so that further code maintenance and future development can be easily managed.