# How to include a project as a project instead of a jar inside another project using Ant?

Tags: java, jar, ant, weblogic

I have 2 projects:
Project: A and 
Project: B (independent)

B is included as a dependency jar inside A. I have to modify code in B so as to make project A work locally. I am not allowed to push changes in B so I am trying to make changes in B locally and include B as an application project inside A instead of jar.

Technologies used: Ant, weblogic, java, eclipse.
I'm new to ant and weblogic. I am looking for config in build.xml not in eclipse settings so that it works in weblogic.

So far, I have tried using `<antcall>` as in link [Building other, dependent projects with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030751/building-other-dependent-projects-with-ant)
but I got compile error.

I also tried including as local jar using  inside  in project A build.xml

```
<target name="compile" depends="clean, update-dependencies">
<javac destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
 <classpath>
                <pathelement path="C:\...\B.jar" />
            </classpath>
</javac>
</target>
```

Comment: OP Should remove java tag from this Q

Comment: I don't know Ant, I use maven for depdendency management but I have a doubt: if you use this workaoround based on local ProjectB modified this solution is not portable in other environments or by other developers so Warning!